# SQL: Need Customer ID, then all column names that are not = 0

Tags: mysql, xml, dynamic

I have a table with a customer ID, and then 30+ columns with a 0 or a 1. I'd like to return in the first column the customer ID, and then in the second column the name of the column that <> 0.
Ex of what the table has:

```
CustomerID, Product1, product2, product3, ...
123456         0          1          1
```

What I'd like to Return:

```
123456, Product2
123456. Product3
...
```

The code I'm using so far...

Comment: that'd be an "unpivot" query. you'd be better off rebuilding your db in a properly normalized form, which will also answer your question for you. mysql has a limit on columns in a table. what happens when you reach limit+1 products? now you're totally hooped.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to re-design your database to better meet your  requirements.

Given the current scenario should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT CustomerID,'Product1' FROM yourtable WHERE product1<>0
UNION 
SELECT CustomerID,'Product2' FROM yourtable WHERE product2<>0
UNION 
SELECT CustomerID,'Product3' FROM yourtable WHERE product3<>0
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to unpivot the table, which will be ugly, but can be done simply by using a sufficent amount of unions, like this;

```
SELECT CustomerId, 'Product1' as product FROM mytable WHERE product1 != 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CustomerId, 'Product2' as product FROM mytable WHERE product2 != 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CustomerId, 'Product3' as product FROM mytable WHERE product3 != 0
UNION ALL
   ....
UNION ALL
SELECT CustomerId, 'Product31' as product FROM mytable WHERE product31 != 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CustomerId, 'Product32' as product FROM mytable WHERE product32 != 0;
```

Comment: Here's some code that gets me halfway there...                                ;with C(TableXML) as
    (
      select *
      from mytable
      --where ID = 6
      for xml path('T'), elements xsinil, type
    )
    select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as ColumnName
    from C
      cross apply C.TableXML.nodes('/T/*') as T(X)
    where T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') <> '0'